# how to configure codeigniter mod_rewrite on wamp?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, wamp

Hi guys could you please tell me how can I configure codeigniter mod_rewrite on wamp?

I've tried enabling it through the wamp menu(wamp-->apache-->apache modules-->rewrite module) and restarting wamp but it's like nothing happened.

I'm asking you guys this cause I need to get rid of the index.php in my codeigniter urls through .htaccess

Answer (score 5):

There are total 4 easy steps that you need to follow (I am considering you have WAMP installed on `C:\wamp` and CodeIgniter has been to extracted to `C:\wamp\www\codeigniter\`):

1. Create a .htaccess file as mentioned in http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite but replace `RewriteBase /` with `RewriteBase /codeigniter/` according to your path.
2. Place this file in `C:\wamp\www\codeigniter\` folder
3. Open the httpd.conf file either from `WAMP->Apache->httpd.conf` or manually from `C:\wamp\bin\Apache\conf\httpd.conf` then locate the line `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` and replace the hash(#) from the beginning so that the complete line becomes `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`. Now Restart Apache.
4. Finally open the file `C:\wamp\www\codeigniter\application\config\config.php` and replace `$config['index_page'] = "index.php";` with this `$config['index_page'] = "";`

Your URLs should now be clean example `http://localhost/codeigniter/blog` etc.

In case it didn't work, refer to the official wiki: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite

Answer (score 2):

1. Follow the steps above (ans 1) to get **mod_rewrite enabled**.
2. To check if enabled, use the WAMPManager menu like so:
   **wampmanager -> Apache -> Module** (Scroll the list and make sure is ticked)
3. create/edit .htaccess on your root CI folder where index.php located.

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

       RewriteEngine On

       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

   </IfModule>
   ```

   [CodeIgniter URLs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html)
4. Edit **config.php** to `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Answer (score 1):

create/edit .htaccess on your root CI folder (where index.php is located)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

may be .htaccess file in your root(application folder) what deny write.
change it to allow from all