# Remove index.php from URL

Tags: codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter 2.1.0 and to remove **index.php** from url I follow [Codeigniter 2.0.0](http://taggedzi.com/articles/display/codeigniter-2-htaccess-and-friendly-urls)

but it does not work for me. Actually my web application url is

```
http://localhost/my_site/admin/index.php/users
```

and I want

```
http://localhost/my_site/admin/users
```

Comment: Try closing some of those open questions

Comment: Check my answer to a similar question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014547/how-to-configure-codeigniter-mod-rewrite-on-wamp/11338013#11338013

Comment: @Ahmad Zafar I followed & also set/unset $config['uri_protocol'] from 'AUTO' to REQUEST_URI but browser says The requested URL /mysite/admin/projects was not found on this server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Sajid I used below code try I may be it will solve your problem.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /your_folder/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /



RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[^/]*/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.+) $1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

And don't forget to open your configuration file (application/config/config.php) and edit the following two options:

```
$config['base_url']
$config['index_page']
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create .htaccess file in project folder and write:

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 # Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L] 

  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 index.php
  </IfModule>

   #And You don't need to define in base_url in config file:

   $config['base_url'] = '';// blank it.

   I hope it will work perfectly ...
```